# Monitor network nodes for availability

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp

I'm installing a network at a factory with around 200-300 PLC's. I have looked into spiceworks and similar solutions, and all of them are more or less computer / printer minded.

What I wan't is:
A solution that's able to scan my network / get a list from me at setup, and continuously check for me, if all the network nodes in the list are active. Ping / SNMP - it doesn't matter.

If a node goes down, the solution should warn me some how .. Does anyone know of such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions available which are able to give you a good overview of a current network status and sends out alerts (SMS, Mail, ...)

- **Check_mk + Nagios:** https://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk.html this is a common implementation for monitoring networked services and the network itself. It is not very easy to install, but experience shows that it is a reliable solution. The auto-scanning not an option here, but adding services is not too hard in the web interface.
- **Solarwinds:** http://www.solarwinds.com/ This is a commercial solution which does support subnet scanning and SNMP scanning.

I would go into one of these directions, but there are many more alternatives of course. It is a matter of how much time and money you want to invest.